# Cast one generic type to another

Tags: generics, rust

I need a function that deserializes an item and sets it to a struct. And I need a function that sets an item to a struct, but that item might not implement `DeserializeOwned`.
I need something like this:

```
    struct SomeStruct<T> {
      item: T,
    }
    
    impl<T> SomeStruct<T> {
      pub fn set_item_from_json<D: DeserializeOwned>(&mut self, json: String) {
        let item: D = serde_json::from_str(&json).unwrap();
        self.item = item;
      }

      pub fn set_item(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.item = item;
      }
    }
```

The code above, as expected, doesn't work because `mismatched types [E0308] expected type parameter 'T', found type parameter 'D'` occures in `set_item_from_json`. What can I do?

Comment: Do you want to be able to call `set_item_from_json()` only when `T: DeserializeOwned`?

Comment: You want to take `&str`, not `String`.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman String or &str doesn't matter, it's just an example. My real case is more complex. Your solution works. I didn't know that I could define a generic type in `impl<T>` and constrain `T` just for one function. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`where` clauses can constrain existing generic parameters:

```rust
pub fn set_item_from_json(&mut self, json: String)
where
    T: DeserializeOwned,
{
    let item = serde_json::from_str(&json).unwrap();
    self.item = item;
}
```

Alternatively, put it in the `impl`:

```rust
impl<T: DeserializeOwned> SomeStruct<T> {
    pub fn set_item_from_json(&mut self, json: String) {
        let item = serde_json::from_str(&json).unwrap();
        self.item = item;
    }
}

impl<T> SomeStruct<T> {
    pub fn set_item(&mut self, item: T) {
        self.item = item;
    }
}
```